# The Deny the permission of mounting any drives to a user

Tags: linux, permissions, users, disk

I'm using Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon.

There are multiple partitions on `/dev/sda`. `/dev/sda1` is where the system resides, `/dev/sda2, ..., /dev/sdaX` are NTFS partitions. There are two users `admin` and `user`.

`admin` can mount any drive through the menu (the method involves `udiskctl`, IIRC). `user` was created as a standard user and can do it too. How can I deny this to `user`?

`user` belongs to the following groups: `adm`,`audio`, `cdrom`, `dialout`, `dip`, `fax`, `floppy`, `fuse`, `plugdev`, `scanner`, `tape`, `video`.

Is `plugdev` the group I should remove him from or maybe `fuse`?

Comment: user belongs to the following groups: adm,audio, cdrom, dialout, dip, fax, floppy, plugdev, scanner, shared-config, tape, video.

Is plugdev the group I should remove him from or maybe fuse?

Where do you list `fuse`?

Comment: what the heck is `shared-config`? samba?

Comment: I missed the `fuse`, rechecked and fixed. `shared-config` was created by me for file permissions, removing it from the list

Comment: AFAIK, `udisks` and/or `udev` are most likey automagically configured to allow this.  I can't remember the exact configuration changes needed. arrrgh

Answer (score 0):

The permission udiskctl using is based on a polkit policy, look here for an example:

> https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks#Configuration
>   Check what you current polkit policy states (in the arch example it grants the permission to the storage group). Either remove the user from the appropriate groups or modify the policy.

Comment: Please see the edited OP

Comment: @marmistrz Please see edited answer.

Comment: `sudo grep -ri udisks /etc/polkit-1/` shows nothing - I don't have `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d` at all. See files provided by udisks2: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11971745/     Grepping these files indicates no occurence of the case-insensitive string `group`

Comment: @marmistrz I guess  `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.UDisks2.conf` is the file you are looking for.

Comment: And what should I do with it?

Comment: @marmistrz honestly, I'm not sure, I'm not too familiar with polkit. I would try to remove the section starting with the comment `Anyone can send message`, restart the service and see if anything changed. Otherwise, I would try to implement something like what is in the arch wiki, ask specifically about changing the polkit policy or searching info about it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the user from the group `plugdev`